# can't make the sum of columns in 2 connected tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am quit new to MySQL.

I have 2 tables:

**Table 1: client_debts (*id*, client_name, total_debts)**

**Table 2: client_details (*id*, *client_id*, payments)**

Where client_id is the foreign key of table 2 and is connected to table 1 id column.

What I need to do is, to create an PHP-HTML ***(No problem with this part)*** table that gives me the total debts of a client, with the total of his payments to compare how much he still have. IF his payments are equal, I want to remove his name from the HTML table.

**What I tried ?**

I tried this SQL query:

```
    SELECT (SELECT sum(total_debts) FROM client_debts) AS 'TOTAL', 
    (SELECT sum(payments) FROM client_details) AS 'Total Payed' 
    FROM client_debts INNER JOIN client_details 
    ON client_debts.id = client_details.client_id
```

And I have got this:

[image]

And the results are only for the first id and it is duplicated to all rows.

So how can I do this for every client?

Comment: you need `group by` and also provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Query

```
SELECT client_debts.id,sum(total_debts)  AS 'TOTAL', 
    sum(payments) AS 'Total Payed' 
    FROM client_debts 
    INNER JOIN client_details 
    ON client_debts.id = client_details.client_id
    GROUP BY client_debts.id;
```

I hope this will work and in this query get all client id and its SUM.

Comment: It works, but how to do the part that said, that we don't want to make this calculation where total = total_payed ?

Comment: `SELECT client_debts.id,sum(total_debts)  AS 'TOTAL', 
    sum(payments) AS 'Total Payed' 
    FROM client_debts 
    INNER JOIN client_details 
    ON client_debts.id = client_details.client_id
    GROUP BY client_debts.id HAVING 2 != 3;`